# Can WIFI be turned off programmatically

Tags: android, wifi

How can wifi be turned off/on programmatically and do is rooted or system app required for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Permissions are required.

I just wrote this app that toggles Wifi.

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.stackoverflow.q5766518"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toggle Wifi" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main Activity**

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
        final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(!wifi.isWifiEnabled());
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`WIFI_ON` is a secure setting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#WIFI_ON); only apps signed by the system firmware will be able to hold the proper permission and adjust it using the SDK.

---

**UPDATE**

[`setWifiEnabled()`](http://goo.gl/scdnU) probably supports this, as was pointed out in the comments. I don't see evidence of a permission being required, but if there is one, you'll get a stack trace that should point out what's needed. My apologies for forgetting about this path.

Comment: What about WifiManager and all the app widgets that toggle Wifi on/off? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Comment: @Thane Anthem: Ah, my apologies. `setWifiEnabled()` would seem to support this, and a quick scan of the source code does not show any sign of a permission being needed (which is moderately disturbing). I will update my answer momentarily.

Comment: Permissions do appear to be required, as I received errors about lacking three permissions while writing the app I posted elsewhere in this thread.

Comment: @Thane Anthem: Well, at least they are all ones you can ask for (vs. having to be a firmware-signed app).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. wifimangr.setWifiEnabled(false);

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > Create an object of Wifimanager..and call the method setWifiEnabled to "false".
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >                                                   **wifimangr.setWifiEnabled(false);**

you need CHANGE_WIFI_STATE permission todo this.