# How can I **disable** the Internet?

Tags: android

I am developing an application. In which, I want to disable the using Internet for some time, especially if he has homework. How can I **disable** the Internet ?

Comment: best S/O question title ever.

Comment: Think carefully about something like this. If your goal is to prevent cheating, or distractions, it's trivial to have a second phone/etc. Do you *really* need to disable the internet connection?

Comment: Airplane mode disables the internet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249245/how-to-set-the-airplane-mode-on-to-true-or-on

Comment: Note that airplane mode cannot be changed on Android 4.2+ from a normal SDK application. Only ones signed by the firmware signing key or are installed on the system partition can hold the requisite permission.

Comment: @CommonsWare really can you post a blog about "how to sign  by the firmware signing key". I do not understand how I can do that ? I have read but I do not get what I should do. Can you explain step by step ?

Comment: "I do not understand how I can do that ?" -- you start by building your own ROM mod.

Comment: I should change the ROM file. Am I understand right ?

Comment: why would you want to disable the internet ?

Comment: @njzk2 Why this site refuses to do other peoples homeworks ? The reason is same ( nearly )

Comment: i don't understand. (but that's ok, i don't have another answer to give anyway)

Answer (score 1):

To enable/disable data connection programatically check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555366/enable-disable-data-connection-in-android-programmatically)

To disable / enable wi-fi refer this [tutorial](http://www.hrupin.com/2012/06/how-to-turn-on-turn-off-wifi-connection-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Are there a way to disable the application to be used ?

Comment: I mean I will disable the application. If he click on, system will refuse to open it.

Comment: I dont think that will be possible until you yourself manually lock the settings application in android. One thing you could do is down load the app called "App lock" and lock your setting with it altogether. SO only you know the passcode to open the settings and make whatever changes you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "mobile data" and "wifi state" whithin your application as long as you have the right permissions. 
Also, you can register system wide BroadcastListener to detect when the device is connected to the internet, and do whatever you consider needs to be done.

Comment: How can I listen BroadcastListener then detect the device is trying to connect to the Internet ?

Comment: can you give sample code ? Should I put something on <uses-permission ?

Comment: Get notify when internet becomes available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125284/how-can-we-get-notified-if-the-phone-has-got-internet-access Toggle wifi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766518/can-wifi-be-turned-off-programatically Toggle 3g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535101/how-can-i-turn-off-3g-data-programmatically-on-android

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this using Airplane mode, or via system hooks but the user will still retain the power to connect back. If you disconnect it again, he can disable/remove your app.

Is there an absolute way to restrict the user? I don't believe so. For security reasons alone, Providing this ability to third party applications would be very dangerous.

Comment: how to be first party application ?

Comment: Only system apps get to do that. You'll have to be in the Google Android team to write and include a system level android app I suppose..