# Android - How to block user open Wi-Fi

Tags: android, android-wifi

How do I block user to open their Wi-Fi? They cannot turn on their wifi from the Menu and Setting. When the user turn on their wifi, an alert will show and turn off the wifi. What should I type in my Button(A button that can be turn on and off)'s listener?

Comment: Ok, I've got to ask... why are you trying to block a user from turning on their Wifi?

Comment: If that could be allowed, then there is a new kind of malware.

Comment: @AdamSchiavone My sister always play Facebook, WeChat, Instagram, ...So I want to block her to play

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766518/can-wifi-be-turned-off-programatically), which shows how to toggle Wifi on/off with `WifiManager.setWifiEnabled()`, and the permissions needed. You'll need to listen in with a `BroadcastReceiver` to know when the status has changed. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888502/android-wifi-how-to-detect-when-wifi-connection-has-been-established/5890553#5890553) shows how to do that.

If you don't have root access, you're out of luck. You can still listen for the status change to know *when* it's turned on, but you can't really do anything about it. Maybe throw a warning dialog or something, but you won't be able to turn it off.

Comment: I'm struggling to define root without using the word "root". [Try this link.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_access) I'm guessing, though, if you don't know what root means, you don't have it. Devices don't generally come with it by default.

Comment: That's not a good question for this site. It's a different process for every  device. [XDA Developers Forum](http://www.xda-developers.com/) is a good place to start looking for answers, though.

Comment: So if my sister's phone has enable root, i can use the method about?

Comment: Should work. I haven't tried it, but it's what I would go with.